# Translate Selfdrawn Images to Characterset in SublimeText

Tags: unicode, character-set

I want to create a character-set of images that I draw on Adobe Photoshop and view it in Sublime Text.

For example, character ᔷ from https://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_1400.html#1537
is mapped as (U+1537) and can be copy-pasted into Sublime Text.

Does anyone have any experience doing this? (Sorry if this is a repost.)

Thanks   !

Comment: I don't understand what this Canadian syllable character has to do with your idea to draw glyphs for your own font. Of course you can copy-paste ᔷ into Sublime Text – as long as it finds a font with a glyph for it, it will display it properly (otherwise you'll see a box or something). Can you be more specific about what you actually want to do?

Comment: The relation is that a party was able to have a glyph and have a font represent it. What I want to do is draw a glyph and edit or create a font with it. If I have an image represent an idea then I feel that pulling up the image each time would be less convenient than having it available in a text-editor; so it would be local and not needed to be accepted as a glyph among any other parties.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to do. I have honestly no idea what you mean by "pulling up the image each time", but it doesn't sound like you are planning a new script proposal to the Unicode consortium. Unicode has a range of codepoints meant for private use; maybe that helps. There is software for creating fonts out there, too, but I can't help you with any of that, I'm afraid.